# While setting up DevEco I am not able to set the HarmonyOS SDK path, What is the issue?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos, huawei-account

While setting up DevEco I am not able to set the HarmonyOS SDK path, What is the issue?

Comment: Your network connection can be an Issue. Please check you have good connection before downloading SDK. Also try reinstalling like @shirley mentioned

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the old DevEco and try reinstalling it.

For details, you could follow the [this document](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-guides/software_install-0000001053582415).